# Rnw file doesn't generate plot in pdf

Tags: r, pdf, knitr

I'm working with an `.Rnw` file, trying to generate a plot. However, when I click Compile PDF, I get a blank pdf with just the figure caption and no plot. It looks like this: [image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<fasfd, fig.height=10, fig.cap="first", fig.pos="t", echo=FALSE, fig.width=10>>=
barplot(table(mtcars$gear))
@

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You tag your question with both `knitr` and `sweave`. Which one are you using?

Comment: FWIW, saving your example to a file named `"eg.Rnw"` and then doing `knitr::knit2pdf("eg.Rnw")` gets a  document that does display the plot.

Comment: I'm using `knitr`, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien okay that worked. Thanks! Any idea why it didn't work when I just clicked Compile PDF?

Comment: Nope, can't help you there, since that's an issue with an RStudio feature, and I don't tend to use RStudio.

Comment: Works fine on my RStudio (Version 0.99.893 )

Answer (score 2):

`Sweave` does not provide so many options as `knitr`. To include plots with `sweave` you need to specify `fig= TRUE`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
Without $fig=TRUE$
<<fasfd, fig.height=5, fig.cap="first", fig.pos="t", echo=TRUE, fig.width=10>>=
barplot(table(mtcars$gear))
@
With $fig=TRUE$
<<fig=TRUE>>=
barplot(table(mtcars$gear))
@

A boxplot of the \emph{airquality} data:
\centering
<<fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
data(airquality)
boxplot(Ozone ~ Month, data = airquality)
@

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I never used `knitr`, but the syntax relay reminded me on `sweave`, in this case you need to correct the tag, for example:

```
<<label=fig1,fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE>>=
```

in total:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<label=fig1,fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE>>=

barplot(table(mtcars$gear))
@
\end{document}
```

Comment: The tag syntax OP has is fine for `knitr`.